Release files in WSL2 are invalid
I am trying to install some things I need in WSL2 on Windows 11 (new computer). This has not been a problem in the past and WSL2 generally work pretty well.
I run into this problem:
johan@computer:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 58min 56s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 0min 21s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

It has been like this for a couple of days. Installing packages also fails.
Is there a way to solve this?
I really need to get my environment up and going. What can I do?

Yes i did try to reset the hwclock and I also rebooted a few times, same issue. I have not tried to reinstall but I will do that now.


Is there a way to solve this?

Update WSL to the current version.  You can do that by running
wsl --update

The ICTIMESYNCFLAG_SYNC patch was released back in January 2024.
Source: Clock skew issues megathread
If this still fails to resolve the problem then the time within WSL and Windows is out of sync. I would suggest looking at your time servers and making sure both WSL and Windows was properly configured.

It looks like the clock in WSL2 was in sync with the Windows clock but automatic time updates was for some reason disabled and the Windows clock was out of sync. Enabling automatic time updates solved the issue. I got no idea why that was disabled in the first place.
